# Dynamic html5 element creation using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have an HTML5 file called `index.HTML` which contains two pages with the id name `create_group` and `add_member`

**Page create_group:**

```
<body onLoad="onLoad()">

 <div data-role="page" id="create_group">

 <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" align="center">     

      <h1>Group</h1>

 </div>

  <div data-role="content">


  </div>
```

**Page add_member:**

```
   <-- I want to call this page using "add_member" id with: -->

     $(document).ready(function(){});or$("#add_member").ready(function(){});-->

     <div data-role="page" id="add_member">
        <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false"  data-position="fixed" 
          data-theme="a" align="center">  

            <h1>User Data</h1>
         </div>

  </div>
 </body>
```

**Question:**

How can I create dynamic elements before page load while changing the pages.

Comment: your question isn't clear. loading data using `.load()`? please clarify your question.

Comment: @Omar actually I want to call the add_member page using id...

Comment: so do you want to load some html file into the `create_group `, you dont need either `ready or load` what you need is a ajax call

Comment: @jycr753 [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is an ajax.

Comment: @Omar yeah my bad, i was thinking in something else ...